# Initializing base class members in derived class initializer list

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class that I have to instantiate tons of times. It's something like this:

```
class A
{
  public:

  A() : a1(0.0f), a2(-1) {}

  float a1;
  int   a2;
};

class B : public A
{
  B();
  float b;
};
```

I have in mind 2 ways to implement the ctor of B:

```
B(): A(), b(0.0f) {} // Using the base class ctor.

B(): b(0.0f) { a1 = 0.0f; a2 = -1; } // Not using the base class ctor. Ugly but maybe faster?
```

Which of those is faster?

My member types are basic (int, float, double...) in both base and inherited class.

Compiler: Intel and LLVM.

Comment: Have you tried to measure the times yourself?

Comment: @user2280716 Agree. As Donald Knuth said: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Even if ignoring all considerations of premature optimization, both version will result in the exact same code. The second could even be slower (if ignoring all optimization efforts by the compiler), because the default constructor of `A` will always be called if you don't call one of it's constructors yourself. So just omitting it won't prevent it from being called. And after all I don't think the second will even compile, since you're not supposed to initialize base class members.

Answer (score 2):

The first way is your only option. Your second "option" won't work because `a1` and `a2` are declared in the base class, and hence cannot be initialized in the initializer list of `B`.

The reasoning is that they belong to `A`, so initializing them is the responsibility of `A` and will be done in the constructor of `A`, which is before any other initialization takes place in `B`. No matter what you do, there will always be a constructor of `A` called as the first step of constructing a `B` object. Even if you somehow could avoid this and initialize the members directly from `B`, there's no realistic reason to expect an actual improvement in performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can not initialize members of a base class in the initialization list of a derived class.  The second one will not compile.

You have to pick which one of `A`'s constructors will be called; if you mention none, the default `A()` will be called automatically. There is no way not to call base class constructor.